# executing xp_cmdshell in remote server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
RECONFIGURE
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',1  

declare @cmdstring varchar(1000)

set @cmdstring = 'copy D:\\Mine\\Mine\\Icons\\1355312509_gadu.ico D:\\Mine\\Mine\\1355312509_gadu.ico'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmdstring 

RECONFIGURE
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',0
```

I am trying to execute this on remote server, I am logged in as sysadmin though I am not able to execute, this is the error I get, I have been through earlier post but couldn't find the proper solution

```
output
The device is not ready.
NULL
```

Any help would be apreciated

Won't this code

```
RECONFIGURE
    EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',0
```

at the end of code eliminate those security threats??

This is what I have done and its okay

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    id               INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    name_file        VARCHAR(500),
    depth_tree       VARCHAR(10),
    is_folder_files  VARCHAR(10)
)

/* xp_dirtree selects file from specific location
*  depth_tree       :   depth of the search i.e. subfolders
*  is_folder_files  :   selects folders only or files too
*/

INSERT INTO #temp(name_file, depth_tree, is_folder_files) EXEC xp_dirtree @source_path, 0, 1

-- Must concatenate to have permission for xp_cmdshell
SET @concatenate_string = 'RECONFIGURE EXEC sp_configure ''xp_cmdshell'',1 EXEC MASTER..xp_cmdshell '


-- Generating copy string in bulk
SELECT @cmd_string =    
    ISNULL(@cmd_string, '') + 
    CASE WHEN (LEN(REPLACE(t.name_file, @seperate_value, 1)) <> LEN(t.name_file)) -- if @seperate_value is not in image
        THEN
        (
            SELECT CASE 
                WHEN REPLACE(t.name_file, 'Approach', 1) <> t.name_file OR REPLACE(t.name_file, 'CloseUp', 1) <> t.name_file -- if word Approach or CloseUp is not there in image 
                THEN
                    (
                    SELECT CASE
                    WHEN ((SELECT f.FaceID FROM Face f WHERE CAST(f.Notes AS VARCHAR) = SUBSTRING(t.name_file, 0, CHARINDEX(@seperate_value, t.name_file)-1)) IS NOT NULL) -- when extracted ID from image <> NotesID
                    THEN
                    (
                    @concatenate_string + '''copy ' + @source_path + t.name_file + ' ' 
                    + @destination_path 
                    + (SELECT f.FaceID FROM Face f WHERE CAST(f.Notes AS VARCHAR) = SUBSTRING(t.name_file, 0, CHARINDEX(@seperate_value, t.name_file)-1)) -- Compares and gives the faceID
                    + (SELECT   CASE 
                                    WHEN REPLACE(t.name_file, 'Approach', 1) <> t.name_file THEN '-AS.jpg'' '
                                    WHEN REPLACE(t.name_file, 'CloseUp', 1) <> t.name_file THEN '-BS.jpg'' '
                                    ELSE
                                        'Undefined'
                                END
                       )
                    )
                    ELSE
                        ' '
                    END
                )
                ELSE
                    ' '
                END
        )    
        ELSE
            ' '
    END

FROM #temp t

SELECT @cmd_string + 'RECONFIGURE EXEC sp_configure ''xp_cmdshell'',0'

EXEC (@cmd_string)
```

Comment: why are you using a sql server to copy icon files? I wouldn't let you on any SQL Server I deal with. Disable access to xp_cmdshell

Comment: this is just an example, i could use filesystemobject but will have to have conditions or naming dependent on the value of table

Comment: not a very good one then. Advice still stands: Disable access to xp_cmdshell

Comment: @MitchWheat: what do you suggest, is there serious threat regarding xp_cmdshell??

Comment: `xp_cmdshell` runs with the same privileges as SQL Server itself so it can be misused although the [`xp_cmdshell` proxy account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190359.aspx) has made things a little safer. But a more important question is why you're using a database to copy files? As a general rule, TSQL is a very poor language for interacting with anything outside the database, it's almost always better to use an external script or program. I know that this question is probably a simplified one, but if you can explain your real requirement then someone may have a good solution.

Comment: Thanks @Pondlife for your suggestion, actually we have like a thousand of images with random names, so we have to rename the copied file with the name matching certain name of the old files from the db with some additional string so I thought instead of having a loop why don't we have a set of query that does it. In addition it makes me easy to have different columns conctenate for naming of the new image name as well as checking some conditons, and to add to that its not a regular thing, we run it only once

Comment: You'll still have a loop in the SQL code anyway. If I had to do this I would write a short script to query the file names and other columns from the database, construct the new filenames, and then rename the files. It would be a lot simpler to write and easier to debug than doing it in TSQL. Even if this is a one-time task, TSQL is still a very awkward way to do it.

Comment: Check my edited query above @Pondlife if you want to and do suggest

Comment: Your general technique of generating a script using code is fine; for general code feedback you can post on the [code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But please note that `xp_dirtree` is an undocumented system procedure and there is no guarantee that it will continue to function or even be available in the future. Again, I wouldn't do it this way at all; it would be an interesting exercise to implement a solution using PowerShell (or whatever) and compare the two (something like a [code kata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kata_(programming))).

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, looking forward to ur solutions

Answer (score 2):

I have had this one some time too. I ran the script from server a, where things were on server b. I checked and the only thing (besides credentials, which looks it isn't an issue) was that the filestructure didn't exists on the remote server..

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely an issue with the credentials the SQL Server Service is running under. The account might not have sufficient access to the folders you are trying to copy from or to.

One solution could be attempting to run the task from SQL Server Agent, see also [this discussion on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/d5d8a5fa-a9be-4998-ad23-ec8b03cf19dc).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using T-SQL to do anything outside of SQL Server, which has its own inherited risks, you will need to firstly give the right permissions to the right account to even run `xp_cmdshell`.

You will need a local AD account, as the local "nt service\mssqlserver" account may not exist in your other remote server and so why will never get access to it.

However, before you get the Shell steps itself, do this:

```
USE MASTER;

-- this turns on advanced options and is needed to configure xp_cmdshell
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', '1'
    RECONFIGURE
-- this enables xp_cmdshell
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', '1'
    RECONFIGURE

IF NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT loginname
      FROM   master.dbo.syslogins
      WHERE  name = 'yourdomain\anADaccount')
  BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN [yourdomain\anADaccount] FROM WINDOWS;
    EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'yourdomain\anADaccount', 'accountpassword'
  END

--Create the database role and assign rights to the role
--select DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID('CmdShell_Executor')
IF DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID('CmdShell_Executor') IS NULL
  BEGIN
    CREATE ROLE [CmdShell_Executor] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    GRANT EXEC ON xp_cmdshell TO [CmdShell_Executor]
  END

IF NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT [name]
      FROM   [sys].[database_principals]
      WHERE  [name] = 'yourdomain\anADaccount')
  BEGIN
--Then once done create users and assign to CmdShell_Executor
    CREATE USER [yourdomain\anADaccount] FROM LOGIN [yourdomain\anADaccount];
    EXEC sp_addrolemember[CmdShell_Executor], [yourdomain\anADaccount];
  END
```

Now make sure your AD account also has permissions to the remote server. I strongly suggest you create these AD accounts on each `<<local>>` machine and not under the general domain's AD. You can then control the account to only have read access to a specific folder or location on your remote server.

Now you're ready to run the CMD shell from SQL Server, without the risk of any security holes that someone foreign may gain access to your database and run Shell commands!

```
EXEC    master..xp_cmdshell 'whoami.exe'  --find out what account you're actually using
```

At the end of your procedure, make sure you remove all those permissions!

```
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account NULL
drop user [yourdomain\anADaccount] 
drop role [CmdShell_Executor]
drop login [yourdomain\anADaccount]
```